# Replace content between two words notepad++

Tags: search, replace, notepad++

do you know how to remove a text between two words in notepad ++

```
VALUES (1, NULL, NULL,
VALUES (2, NULL, NULL,
VALUES (3, NULL, NULL,
```

to

```
VALUES (NULL, NULL,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**resolved**

```
VALUES.*?NULL

VALUES\(NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove the first entry from each `VALUES` clause, then try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    VALUES \([^,]+,\s*
Replace: VALUES (
```

Check the demo link below to a working example.

### Demo

Comment: In Notepad++ the parenthesis have to be escaped in the replacement part.

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `VALUES \(\K[^,]+, ?`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
VALUES \(   # literally
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
[^,]+       # 1 or more not comma
, ?         # a comma followed by an optional space
```

**Result for given example:**

```
VALUES (NULL, NULL,
VALUES (NULL, NULL,
VALUES (NULL, NULL,
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]